# gcc : directory : No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, makefile, arm

I am trying to build the mali driver for linux 3.7 kernel from [Here](http://malideveloper.arm.com/develop-for-mali/drivers/open-source-mali-gpus-linux-kernel-device-drivers/).

There is a separate build script like,

```
#!/bin/bash
export KDIR=/path/to/kernel/dir/
..
..
gcc -v//Just for testing purpose printing gcc version
make
gcc -v
...
```

Actual host machine has 2.6 kernel, but im instructing `make` to use linux 3.7 kernel. The above make will call the Makefile of mali driver's makefile.

For the above script,
gcc version prints properly before and after `make` command, but when `make` entered in to kernel directory, gcc is not recognized.

it saying **gcc : directory : No such file or directory**.

same happens to arm-gcc too. Any Guess??

Edit:(make output)

```
make ARCH=arm -C /home/work/linux3.7/ M=/home/work/mali/driver/src/devicedrv/mali modules

make[1] : Entering directory `/home/work/linux3.7/`
gcc : directory : No such file or directory
gcc : directory" : No such file or directory 
<command-line>: warning: missing terminating " character
gcc : directory : No such file or directory
gcc : directory" : No such file or directory 
<command-line>: warning: missing terminating " character
gcc : directory : No such file or directory
gcc : directory" : No such file or directory 
<command-line>: warning: missing terminating " character
gcc : directory : No such file or directory
gcc : directory" : No such file or directory 
<command-line>: warning: missing terminating " character
CC [M]  /home/work/mali/driver/src/devicedrv/mali/common/mali_kernel_core.o
.arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: directory:No such file or directory 
.arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: directory":No such file or directory

make[2] : Leaving directory `/home/work/linux3.7/`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in drivers/gpu/vithar/ump/src/devicedrv/Makefile.common. It assumes that the vithar SDK has been pulled from SVN and has a valid SVN revision (it doesn't).

You have 2 options:
1) Edit the file above to skip invocation of svnversion:

```
- SVN_REV:=$(shell ((svnversion | grep -qv exported && echo -n 'Revision: ' && svnversion) || git svn info | sed -e 's/$$$$/M/' | grep '^Revision: ' || echo ${MALI_RELEASE_NAME}) 2>/dev$
+ SVN_REV=0
```

2) Add to make command line:

```
SVN_REV=0
```

Answer (score 3):

`gcc` *is* recognized, found, and executed. The error "gcc: directory: no such file or directory" is given by `gcc` itself.

For some reason, `gcc` is trying to access "directory" (i.e., *an object called "directory"*), which does not exist.

Maybe a wrong expansion or an unexpected environment variable.

Try checking the appropriate `Makefile` and your `make` command.

For example, if you issued a command such as

```
KDIR="/usr/Linux Kernel directory" CONFIG=pb-virtex5 BUILD=release make
```

there is a risk that the system misinterpret `KDIR`, introducing two nonexistent objects "Kernel" and "directory" as well as an extra quotation mark. Such a possibility **might** explain the symptoms you observe. So, extra spaces in paths are definitely something worth checking.

Comment: `Warning:: Missing terminating " character` also there. Any clue??

Comment: This looks like a string that somehow got messed up and interpreted by `gcc`, maybe because of an extra quotation mark somewhere. Check that Makefile. Did you encounter problems while running `make config`? Did you modify the build environment in any way?

Comment: Also: try posting the whole, say, ten lines of output from the `make` command, as well as the exact `make` command that you issue. It's difficult to diagnose such a problem in the dark. We do not even know during the processing of which subdirectory the error appears in.

Comment: updated Make output. KDIR=/path/to/kernel/ with and without "" gave me same error.

Comment: Something is clearly passing wrong parameters to `gcc`, and the most likely candidate is the build script. I'm afraid we need that too.

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo; you want

```
  echo $(gcc -v)
```

but actually, for that coding

```
  gcc -v
```

is enough.

You should be sure that `gcc` is correctly installed in your `$PATH`. Check with `which gcc`

#### addenda

If you suspect your `Makefile` is wrong, use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) to debug it. Often, just running `remake -x` in a terminal could be enough to understand what is happening.

Perhaps you are passing some weird argument to `gcc` ? Or some wrong `#include`?

Comment: ya.. but both gives me same result. But my objective is not just printing gcc version. why gcc is not recoginized in build process???

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What do you mean by *"gcc is not recognized in build process"*? Maybe you did not install *GCC* or your `$PATH` is wrong.

Comment: $PATH is set with /usr/bin